# Вложенный SQL запрос по структуре таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть бд с такой структурой. Как написать запрос который бы выдавал fio, price, quality и telephone зная только fromUser из таблицы bids?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связи противоречивы.

Comment: А, понял что смущает товарища Akina. Если Вы хотите получить данные пользователя кто сделал ставку - то я не вижу никаких проблем - берёте и делаете запрос к таблице users (тут даже джоинов не надо никаких). А если Вам нужны данные того кто объявил аукцион - то тут Вам без auctionNum (либо id из таблицы bids) никак не обойтись. Ну как бы если данных нет - то их и не взять ниоткуда - всё математически просто.